# ElasticSearch Java api setPercolateFilter

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm migrating form ElasticSearch 1.3 to 2.3.2
I see that Java API was changed for Percolate stuff.
I used filter for percolated document like this:

```
request.setPercolateFilter(filter);
```

New API doesn't have such method. Filter is not supported for percolator. I see only such stuff

```
request.setPercolateQuery(filterQuery);
```

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html) says that we can use filter, but api doesn't have it.

**filter** - Reduces the number queries to execute during percolating. Only the percolator queries that match with the filter will be included in the percolate execution. The filter option works in near realtime, so a refresh needs to have occurred for the filter to included the latest percolate queries.

**query** - Same as the filter option, but also the score is computed. The computed scores can then be used by the track_scores and sort option.

DOes anybody know why filter method was removed